# Upload video direct to YouTube from os x

Tags: php, xcode, macos, youtube, google-api-php-client

I want to upload videos from an Os x application to YouTube. I am building an app for mac on XCode and what I want to do is to give my user the option to give their credentials and upload videos to their channel direct from their mac. 
Like iMovie does.

Now I am uploading the video to server and from server to my own channel.
I am using this https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client library successfully and I am uploading videos from server to my channel on YouTube using php.

So, can I upload to a different YouTube channel by giving email and password to the php or should I find another way to upload the videos direct to YouTube?  Is there any tutorial that shows how to implement this?

Thanking all of you in advance

Comment: You should look into the authentication methods for the Google API, rather than trying to handle user credentials directly.

Comment: I think the information you're looking for is in the [Google Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

Comment: Using oauth2 (I have to call a python script from my php file) we can log in with their own credentials, they can pick from a list of all channels associated with their account. The link opens in a web browser, they choose their account, and then it stores their access tokens so we don't have to prompt them again until it expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube Data API supports the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorizing access to private user data. The list below explains some core OAuth 2.0 concepts:

- When a user first attempts to use functionality in your application that requires the user to be logged in to a Google Account or YouTube account, your application initiates the OAuth2 authorization process.
- Your application directs the user to Google's authorization server. The link to that page specifies the scope of access that your application is requesting for the user's account. The scope specifies the resources that your application can retrieve, insert, update, or delete when acting as the authenticated user.
- If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google will return a token to your application. Depending on your application's type, it will either validate the token or exchange it for a different type of token.
- For example, a server-side web application would exchange the returned token for an access token and a refresh token. The access token would let the application authorize requests on the user's behalf, and the refresh token would let the application retrieve a new access token when the original access token expires.

Reference:

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2

Good to know:

> Note: Requests to Google's authorization server must use https instead of http because the server is only accessible over SSL (HTTPs) and will refuse HTTP connections.

Comment: Refresh tokens can be a pain they only last for so long so you need to make sure you have a cron worker to keep the tokens updated and obtain  new access and refresh tokens when the the old one expires on my server i tend to set this cron to run every 5 mins so long as there is not another version of it already working (i create a .lock file at start and delete it as the last thing in the cron)

Comment: What @Martin suggested is true. That's a huge thing to keep in mind. It can be a pain in the ass. setting up a cron is a perfect way to solve the problem. Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help

### Upload a video

The following code sample calls the API's videos.insert method to add a video to user's channel. The code also utilizes Google_MediaFileUpload class with the resumable upload parameter set to true to be able to to upload the video in chunks.

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video)